# Angular - Pikaday date format not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker, pikaday

I am using [pikaday-angular](https://github.com/nverba/pikaday-angular) directive wraper.
I wanted to show date in MM/DD/YYYY format in inputbox, hence supplied format in directive.

`<input pikaday="example.myPickerObject" format="MM/DD/YYYY">`

When i click on any date it shows up in inputbox in its default date format and not in my supplied format.

Here is the Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/mFyTVKeGgUm6wz553hOB

Am i missing something?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use the format option, you need to import `moment.js` first:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="pikaday.js"></script>
<script src="pikaday-angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xVPXuYoGtRUdbQYipZMe?p=preview).